# VSFTPD Virtual (Guest) Users with @ in username

Tags: ftp

I've setup VSFTPD so when a user connects it'll use a `user_config_dir` search for that connected user and setup a chroot guest session (since there are multiple FTP accounts belonging to multiple users on the server). This works fine with user names that have no special characters. To avoid collisions on usernames I'm setting up each username with a postfix '@domain.tld' - however, the custom rules in `user_config_dir` don't load when the user has an @ symbol in the name. Is there a way around this in VSFTPD - or a setting that needs to be switched?

vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
guest_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
chroot_local_users=YES
pam_service_name=scftp
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/virtual
```

pam.d/scftp

```
auth required /lib/security/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_login
account required /lib/security/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_login
```

vitrtual/usernamewithoutspecialchars

```
write_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
local_root=/home/marco
chroot_local_user=YES
dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
guest_username=marco
```

virtual/user@domain.tld

```
write_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
local_root=/home/marco
chroot_local_user=YES
dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
guest_username=marco
```

It really just seems it won't match the FTP user `user@domain.tld` to the proper virtual file - while `usernamewithoutspecialchars` works just fine.

Comment: have you tried with \@ (escape)

Comment: @MealstroM I have tried both `user@domain.tld` and `user\@domain.tld` as a file name.

Comment: hmm. try to put it in "" or ''

Comment: @MealstroM You realize this is a file name, right? I can log in - it authenticates just not respecting the rules in the file I've setup for virtual user rules.

Answer (score 0):

Linux filesystems can quite happily manage @ in the name of a directory so the problem you are seeing most likely is with vsftpd. Have you tried using `user.domain.tld` in stead of `user@domain.tld`?

Comment: Using a `.` has worked just fine. I've seen other services use @domain.tld before but I suppose they were using PureFTPD or another alternative. Guess this lands in the bug report land

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use SQL or RADIUS backend for auth logins and usernames should be stored as emails in sql db . That works, ive tested it.

Comment: But how do I store custom attributes for it - Again it's not the auth, I can authenticate, it's loading custom rules that doesn't work for logins with `@` in it. Even if I move the auth to SQL won't I still have the same issue?